# Prove that $\lfloor{x}\rfloor=\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x+1}{2}}\bigg\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x+2}{2^2}}\bigg\rfloor+\ldots$

Tags: functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Prove that
>
> $$\lfloor{x}\rfloor=\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x+1}{2}}\bigg\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x+2}{2^2}}\bigg\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x+2^2}{2^3}}\bigg\rfloor+
>  \ldots$$
>   $x\geq{0}$

How should I start? Any hints would be helpful.

Also how would the expression change for $x\lt{0}.$

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @Somos in the comments. I was able to come up with my own solution.
(Adding here if someone ever stumbles upon here looking for a solution.)

Subtract $\lfloor{x}\rfloor$ from both sides.

Then we need to prove that, $$-\lfloor{x}\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x+1}{2}}\bigg\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x+2}{2^2}}\bigg\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x+2^2}{2^3}}\bigg\rfloor+
 \ldots=0$$

We know that, $\lfloor{x}\rfloor=\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x}{2}}\bigg\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x+1}{2}}\bigg\rfloor$

Therefore, $-\lfloor{x}\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x+1}{2}}\bigg\rfloor=-\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x}{2}}\bigg\rfloor$

Subsituting this,

$$-\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x}{2}}\bigg\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x+2}{2^2}}\bigg\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x+2^2}{2^3}}\bigg\rfloor+
 \ldots$$

$$-\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x}{2}}\bigg\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor{\frac{\frac{x}{2}+1}{2}}\bigg\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x+2^2}{2^3}}\bigg\rfloor+
 \ldots$$

Similarly, I reach,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}-\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x}{2^n}}\bigg\rfloor$$

i.e. $$=0$$

Hence Proved.

Comment: I suppose a good start could be expressing $x$ using its binomial expansion $\sum a_n2^n$

Comment: HInt: do you know about $\lfloor x \rfloor = \lfloor \frac{x}2\rfloor + \lfloor \frac{x+1}2\rfloor$ for all real $x$?

Comment: @Somos Yes, I proved that result previously to this one.

Comment: @Somos, Thanks I edited the solution to the question.

Comment: @Somos, But how would the expression change for $x\lt{0}.$

Comment: No change. They are valid for all reals. Check it.

Comment: @Somos not for $x=-0.5$, LHS is $-1$, RHS is $0$.

Comment: True. The problem is floor is not continuous at $0$ from the left. But moidfy the the summation to account for that, and it is true.