# Why isn't this true for $x<0$?

Tags: functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Prove that
>
> $$\lfloor{x}\rfloor=\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x+1}{2}}\bigg\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x+2}{2^2}}\bigg\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x+2^2}{2^3}}\bigg\rfloor+
>  \ldots$$
>   $x\geq{0}$

I asked this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2882804/prove-that-lfloorx-rfloor-bigg-lfloor-fracx12-bigg-rfloor-bigg-lflo) yesterday. Although I was able to come up with a proof, the second part was left unanswered.

I proved it using,

> Subtract $\lfloor{x}\rfloor$ from both sides.
>
> Then we need to prove that,
>   $$-\lfloor{x}\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x+1}{2}}\bigg\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x+2}{2^2}}\bigg\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x+2^2}{2^3}}\bigg\rfloor+
>  \ldots=0$$
>
> We know that,
>   $\lfloor{x}\rfloor=\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x}{2}}\bigg\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x+1}{2}}\bigg\rfloor$
>
> Therefore,
>   $-\lfloor{x}\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x+1}{2}}\bigg\rfloor=-\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x}{2}}\bigg\rfloor$
>
> Subsituting this,
>
> $$-\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x}{2}}\bigg\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x+2}{2^2}}\bigg\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x+2^2}{2^3}}\bigg\rfloor+
>  \ldots$$
>
> $$-\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x}{2}}\bigg\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor{\frac{\frac{x}{2}+1}{2}}\bigg\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x+2^2}{2^3}}\bigg\rfloor+
>  \ldots$$
>
> Similarly, I reach,
>
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}-\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x}{2^n}}\bigg\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor{\frac{\frac{x}{2^n}+1}{2}}\bigg\rfloor$$
>
> i.e. $$=0$$

My question is,as $\lfloor{x}\rfloor=\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x}{2}}\bigg\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x+1}{2}}\bigg\rfloor$ is true $\forall x\in{\mathbb{R}}$.

Why isn't
$$\lfloor{x}\rfloor=\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x+1}{2}}\bigg\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x+2}{2^2}}\bigg\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor{\frac{x+2^2}{2^3}}\bigg\rfloor+
 \ldots$$ true $\forall x\in{\mathbb{R}}$.

Also how would the expression change for $x\lt{0}$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x=-1$ the lest side is $-1$ and the right side is $0$.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out. But why is that?

Comment: $\frac {-1+2^{n}} {2^{n+1} }=\frac  1 2 -\frac 1 {2^{n+1} }$. This number lies between $0$ and $1$ (strictly less than $1$ so the integer part is $0$. Thus every term on the right side of the equation is $0$.

Comment: What is my wrong with my prove then?

Comment: @prog_SAHIL: At the very least, your error is that you haven't actually checked what your proof says when $x<0$; the number at the end is $-1$, not $0$.

Comment: @Hurkyl, understood. Thank you.